# WA in CPRMT(common permutation)

Tags: c, function

```
#include<stdio.h>

void compare(char a[], char b[]);
void sort(char a[], char b[], char c[], int k);
int main()
{

char a[1001], b[1001];
while((scanf("%s%s", a,b))!=EOF)
{
    compare(a, b);
}
return 0;
}   
void compare(char a[], char b[])
{
int i,j,k,l,m;
i=0;k=0;j=0;
char c[1001];
while(a[i]!='\0')
{
    while(b[j]!='\0')
    {
        l=a[i];
        m=b[j];
        if(l==m)
        {
            c[k]=a[i];
            k++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
    j=0;
}
c[k]='\0';
sort(a,b,c,k);

}

void sort(char a[], char b[], char c[], int k)
{
int i,m,n,j,o,p,h,l[k];
for(i=0;i<=k;i++)
{
    l[i]=c[i];
}
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<k-1;j++)
    {
        if(l[j]>l[j+1])
        {
            m=l[j];
            l[j]=l[j+1];
            l[j+1]=m;
            c[j]=l[j];
            c[j+1]=l[j+1];
        }
    }
}
i=0;
while(l[i+1]!='\0')
{
    if(l[i]==l[i+1])
    {
        m=0;
        n=0;
        j=0;
        while(a[j]!='\0')
        {
            if(a[j]==l[i])
            {
                m=m+1;
            }
            j++;
        }
        j=0;
        while(b[j]!='\0')
        {
            if(b[j]==l[i])
            {
                n=n+1;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if(m<=n)
        {
            h=m;

        }
        else
        {
            h=n;
        }
        o=m*n;
        p=0;
        while(c[i+p+h]!='\0')
        {
            c[i+p+h]=c[i+p+o];
            l[i+p+h]=l[i+p+o];
            p++;
        }
    }
    i++;
}
printf("%s\n", c);
}
```

i am still getting WA to this question...can someone sugggest me some more test cases....
i have tried the following test cases
input
pretty
women
walking
down
the
street
test
totter

and the output is-
e
nw
et
ett

i think i am skipping some test cases........if someone know some more test cases please let me know..

Comment: And what exactly is the code supposed to do?

Comment: it is supposed to input two words and than print the common characters in them in alphabetical order.More description  about the problem is given in the following link http://www.spoj.com/problems/CPRMT/